# Where to handle authorization result in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authorization

In Asp.NET Core 2.0, where is the correct place to decide what to do with authorization result, e.g. redirect to forbidden page, or return 403?

I know I can use `CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToAccessDenied`

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddCookie(option =>
  {
      option.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
      {
      }
  })
```

but that does not seem to be the correct place. It is too late imho.

I would expect that it is done by AuthorizationFilter, but I'm not using it, nor I see it in the FiltersCollection:

```
  services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
      options.Filters.OfType<AuthorizationFilter>().Any(); //false;
  });
```

Comment: I would also like to know what the recommended approach is. Here is the [rel 2.0.0 implementation in the Github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/Events/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs#L62) - it does a 403 for this event if it's an ajax request.